# Realistic time frame for GRE scores to appear in My GRE account

Tags: gre

I'm looking to take the GRE soon, and wondering what is the realistic timeline in your experience for the scores to appear in the My GRE account.

ETS states scores take 10-15 days for scores to appear. I've read on other forums that it takes considerably less time than that.

My program allows reporting of the official score, and allows ETS to submit the GRE upon admission.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe, 3-4 years ago (woah...) when I took the test, it took approximately a month for the scores to appear. When you leave the test they will give you a score right there for the math and reading portions of the exam-- they state that these may change, but from what I've heard, and my own experience, they don't.

Things may have changed since I took it, however. Although, since human graders are still required for the writing portion, I doubt it.

Comment: I only have my own data point to add, but one of my scores changed just a little (by 4 points)

Comment: "A little"? 4 points really seems like a huge difference -- mine did not change (Took it in November 2015).